# Importing a package from AWS lambda temp directory in Python 3.8

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-requests

The problem I have is similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471753/importing-python-package-from-aws-lambda-tmp-directory) but the answer doesn't work for me.
I am trying to import Python library (let's say `xgboost`) from `/tmp` folder in AWS Lambda.

Library `requests` is added to Lambda layer and what I did is:

```
import json
import io
import os
import zipfile
import requests
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/tmp/')
sys.path.append('/tmp/')

os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = "/var/task"

def get_pkgs(url):
    print("Getting Packages...")
    re = requests.get(url)
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(re.content))
    print("Extracting Packages...")
    z.extractall("/tmp/")
    print("Packages are downloaded and extracted.")
    
def attempt_import():
    print("="*50)
    print("ATTEMPT TO IMPORT DEPENDENCIES...")
    print("="*50)
    import xgboost
    print("IMPORTING DONE.")
    
def main():
    URL = "https://MY_BUCKET.s3.MY_REGION.amazonaws.com/MY_FOLDER/xgboost/xgboost.zip"

    get_pkgs(URL)
    attempt_import()
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    main()
    return "Hello Lambda"
```

The error I get is `[ERROR] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'`. I gave my S3 bucket all necessary permissions, and I am positive that Lambda can access the `.zip` file since the `requests.get` works and variable `z` returns:

`<zipfile.ZipFile file=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fddaf31c400> mode='r'>`

Comment: Downloading packages in the lambda execution is wasting your $. Instead, you should either package your dependencies into the deployment package or build a lambda layer.

Comment: @jellycsc The issue is I already have multiple packages in 5 layers, that are close to 260MB which is the limit. Temporary lambda folder has additional space of 512MB so this solution can work to me.

Comment: Ok, I see. You can try EFS integration then.

Comment: @jellycsc Do you mean Sagemaker? Can you send some reference/material?

Comment: No, here is what I mean. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my code above works and I had a rather silly error. Instead of zipping the `xgboost` package folders (`xgboost`, `xgboost.libs` and `xgboost.dist-info`) I actually zipped their parental folder which I named `package-xgoboost`, and that didn't worked in AWS lambda. Be sure that you actually zip those 3 folders directly.

Also, make sure your `xgboost` library is up-to-date. Previously I used version 1.2.1 which didn't work either. Upgrading the library and zipping the newest `xgboost` version (in my case 1.3.3) finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the boto3 library to download the file from S3 to /tmp directory as explained in
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

Comment: This could be the solution, but the issue is when you try to import large python package (such as `xgboost`), downloaded `.zip` file and its extracted folder in `tmp` directory are larger than 500MB which results in: `[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`

Comment: `tmp` directory or ephemeral storage of Lambda function can be expanded up to 10GB now.